# Android Twitter API How to get a String of the text in the TweetView?

Tags: android, twitter

is it possible to get the actual tweet itself from the tweet view and put it into the string?

```
 // TODO: Use a more specific parent
    final ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    // TODO: Base this Tweet ID on some data from elsewhere in your app
    long tweetId = 797098212599496704L;
    TweetUtils.loadTweet(tweetId, new Callback<Tweet>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {
            TweetView tweetView = new TweetView(Start.this, result.data);
            parentView.addView(tweetView);




        }
```

This is currently what I have to grab a tweet and place it in the tweet view, now I would like to extract the tweet.